# Create new address in Ethereum using Nethereum

Tags: nethereum

I try to create new account.

```
var web3 = new Nethereum.Geth.Web3Geth();

var ecKey = Nethereum.Signer.EthECKey.GenerateKey();
var privateKey = ecKey.GetPrivateKeyAsBytes().ToHex();
var account = new Account(privateKey);
```

in account i recived

```
{"privateKey":"0x062f0c51f1949b6cf14329df0fe59c739f98fdfdbef8a70e885c1d028f999a12","address":"0xDd8414810DC6111BEed80383D20AA2A0313BCd51","transactionManager":{"defaultGasPrice":20000000000,"defaultGas":21000,"client":null,"transactionReceiptService":{}},"nonceService":null}
```

but in testchain  this address not added

```
web3.eth.accounts
["0x12890d2cce102216644c59dae5baed380d84830c", "0x13f022d72158410433cbd66f5dd8bf6d2d129924", "0x3a2e25cfb83d633c184f6e4de1066552c5bf4517", "0xaf7c2c210d31245cf332fc1d820bdfd77d1e3555", "0xfd1a70a36f6369d369ce58fe3aa012eb2d8593ab", "0xb6d706ddeece5f9c118073ddceaca5578eea474d", "0xbf5c0f806d6cd0778b8263e803315422a7afd684", "0x711cdc94ae25c5b2f2005b10c13b67bccb82fea7", "0x6d5d2f40cc9f353b83f9a2f53615d3ecbf5447f5", "0x04ce8794628f6640636032cd8e44e62e80816871", "0x7429958b6ba7fc693ef34c466b00f4d34633e6a0", "0xe24d16f8aa08f384cfc480e97a000c53d04c36e5", "0x3448664731d7d1e29078d0f72f6f5db826fec8d7", "0x38bef2ee44b565274789e7fa3b212ddca8b175cc", "0x48a44c89a45fb9a35ebe34dfada675f1473f39e6", "0x009c366f337bbc672d383c50ffa60654c5ca54a3", "0xf2be7e6940ce3827d07fa12c3df8a9167d92da30", "0x3193aca2ea0dc9e841ac237283fa6ba22fe473dd"]
```

What i must do to create new account?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to create a new account

```
public async Task<string> CreateNewEthereumAddressAsync(string password)
{
  return await web3.Personal.NewAccount.SendRequestAsync(password);
}
```

don't send it a plain text password.  Do some salting and hashing on the plaintext password before sending it to this function.